# why wont alert drop to 0 for gcp alert even though the time threshold is 1 minute?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

So I have created an alert from a log based metric for the error count of a kubernetes container. The alert count value never drops below 1 even with the timeframe of 1 minute and I think it should drop to 0 as the alert isn't that frequent. I have created other alerts that do drop to 0 so I am not sure if it is the frequency of the alert or I have misconfigured something in the alerts. So is there something wrong with my log based metrics here.  [image] [image] Or is it with my alert? [image]

Comment: All seems correct for me. I didn't catch your issue? Is it because you haven't a line when 0 alert?

Comment: yeah because it doesn't hit 0 it is always one continuous alert, so no more alerts get sent out

Comment: If you think that this is an issue try to report it at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). More details you can find at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)